# Why did Latin prefix a(d)- to vis(um)?

Tags: etymology, prefix

In other words, why didn't *visum* itself shift to mean "opinion"? What does *ad-* contribute to this semantic shift?

> #### advice [13]

> Like modern French *avis*, advice
> originally meant ‘opinion’, literally ‘what seems
> to one to be the case’. In Latin, ‘seem’ was
> usually expressed by the passive of the verb
> *vidēre* ‘see’; thus, *vīsum est*, ‘it seems’ (literally
> ‘it is seen’). With the addition of the dative first
> person pronoun, one could express the notion of
> opinion: *mihi vīsum est*, ‘it seems to me’. It
> appears either that this was partially translated
> into Old French as *ce m’est a vis*, or that the past
> participle *vīsum* was nominalized in Latin,
> making possible such phrases as *ad (meum)
> vīsum* ‘in (my) view’; but either way it is certain
> that ***a(d)-* became prefixed to *vīs(um)***, producing
> a new word, *a(d)vis*, for ‘opinion’. It was
> originally borrowed into English without the *d*,
> but learned influence had restored the Latin
> spelling by the end of the 15th century. As to its
> meaning, ‘opinion’ was obsolete by the mid 17th century, but already by the late 14th century the
> present sense of ‘counsel’ was developing.
>       The verb *advise* [14] probably comes from
> Old French *aviser*, based on *avis*.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto, p 9 Right column.

[image]

*Oxford Latin Dictionary* (2012 2e), p 2290 Right column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Etymonline:

> late 13c., auys "opinion," from Old French avis "opinion, view, judgment, idea" (13c.), from phrase **ço m'est à vis** "it seems to me," or from Vulgar Latin *mi est visum "in my view," ultimately from Latin visum, neuter past participle of videre "to see" (from PIE root *weid- "to see"). Meaning "opinion offered as worthy to be followed, counsel" is from late 14c.

So the *ad-* is actually not from Latin, but a hypercorrection back when English writers were adopting Latinate forms of words originally from French.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_spelling_reform#16th_and_17th_centuries)